# PackageReferences - is there a way how to force inclusion order?

Tags: msbuild

I have a project that looks like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="TypescriptCommonProperties.MSBuild" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Each package contains .targets file - TypescriptCommonProperties.MSBuild punch of common variables, Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild is the msbuild typescript official tooling. I tried to experiment with the order - but each time I end up with Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild properties being evaluated before the TypescriptCommonProperties.MSBuild properties.

Inlining the properties into the csproj works, but I'd like to have a common "settings" file - is there a way how to force it ?